# Conditional update Dynamodb on nested object

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to learn to use DynamoDB with C#
I have Partial updates, Put, Delete working.
Conditional update works (If the Attributes is part of root object).

I have the following model created.

[image]

Person with a lot of attributes.
The following works:

```
Expression expr = new Expression();
expr.ExpressionStatement = "Age = :age";
expr.ExpressionAttributeValues[":age"] = 26;

UpdateItemOperationConfig config = new UpdateItemOperationConfig
{
    ConditionalExpression = expr,
    ReturnValues = ReturnValues.AllNewAttributes
};

Document updatedPerson2 = personCatalog.UpdateItem(doc, config);
```

But what if my condition was on the Pet Name?
I have tried a couple of approaches with no luck eg:

```
expr.ExpressionStatement = "Pet.Name = :name";
expr.ExpressionAttributeValues[":name"] = "Lilleper";
```

Hope someone can help :) Or just nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Strange.
If I cange it to:

    expr.ExpressionStatement = "Pet.Age = :age";
    expr.ExpressionAttributeValues[":age"] = 30;

it works? Doesn't string work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try externalizing the Name sub-attribute name to ExpressionAttributeNames.

```
Expression expr = new Expression();
expr.ExpressionStatement = "Pet.#name = :name";
expr.ExpressionAttributeNames["#name"] = "Name";
expr.ExpressionAttributeValues[":name"] = "Lilleper";
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks for the help.